# PHP: Defining relative paths compatible with HTML Tags

Tags: php, html, parsing, relative-path

Consider the following directory structure:

- ROOT
- ------ **images**
- ............... *logo.png*
- ------ **includes**
- ............... *vars.php*
- ------ **layout**
- ............... *content.php*
- ------ *index.php*

How do I define a path constant for *logo.png* in **vars.php** that is accessible in both **index.php** and **content.php**? Should be compatible with HTML Tags as a relative path.

```
<img src="<?php echo IMAGE_PATH; ?>">
```

which should be parsed as

```
<img src="images/logo.png"> <!-- if used in index.php -->
```

and

```
<img src="../images/logo.png"> <!-- if used in content.php -->
```

**New Question (EDIT): Does root-relative path work when including php files using *include* / *require* methods?**

Comment: You should use absolute paths.

Comment: Why can't it be static? Why can't you always provide the absolute path?

Comment: But I get directory paths (like c:\Hosting\j349j\html\images\logo.png) which works fine for php includes but fails in html tags. Also, an absolute web-path such as http://domain.com/images/logo.png... i thought this was not a recommended way of including images/stylesheets.

Comment: @gAMBOOKa

For images you should provide de full URL path, and not the filesystem path. Then it will work both in PHP and HTML img tags or css.

Comment: Just put there /images/logo.png in all pages. Its going to work.

Comment: @Havenard: even for PHP include methods?

Comment: @rogeriopvl: I believe using absolute paths that way forces the browser to query the url for dns lookups

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try setting the `<base>` tag in the `<head>` section of your code.

All your images, css, and js files will use this instead of the url in the address bar.

[Info on base](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_base.asp)

Comment: And url's would be like `images/blah.png`, without a leading `/`.

Comment: I like your thinking but in certain cases, where modular components are concerned, the paths might need to be relative to the module directory rather than the root directory.

Comment: @gAMBooka, your right but those cases probably occur less often and could be hard coded.

Comment: But again, that's an absolute url and brings a dns lookup penalty that I'd like to avoid. Crap! I'm all confused now!

Comment: Note that changing the base URL will affect any relative URL and not just relative URLs with a relative URL path.

Comment: Thanks, its been a great help.

Answer (score 3):

Absolute url or root paths will give you the least amount of headaces. Trust me, when the system grows you'll regret that setup.

It is a perfectly legal way to reference things. (as you ask in the comments)

If you're worried about setups between domains, just create a config variable with the absolute path to the domain / directory / etc

Comment: Is there a reason you prefer `absolute`, as opposed to `root-relative`, paths?

Comment: Setup between domains is not the issue. But doesn't using absolute paths for HTML tags (images/stylesheets) carry a performance penalty?

Comment: I believe it does, which is one of the reasons I prefer root-relative.

Comment: using absolute paths everywhere is always going to add weight to your pages (and css for that matter). Simply put, 'http://www.mydomain.com/' is longer than '/'

Comment: I am talking about the concept in general.

Answer (score 3):

You can use *"root-relative"* paths. Simply link to everything with a forward slash at the beginning, i.e.

```
<img src="/images/logo.png">
```

This will resolve to `http://yoursite.com/images/logo.png` from every page on yoursite.com.

Comment: And called a 'root-relative' path (to the best of my knowledge, anyway). =)

Comment: @ricebowl: No, it’s an *absolute path*.

Answer (score 1):

simply specify all paths as relative to the root

```
<img src="/images/logo.png"> <!-- will work anywhere  -->
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest, primarily, that you use root-relative paths. This is only to reduce the complications of moving your site to another host, and also it allows for consistent paths (rather than using an `if()` condition to test from where the script's being run).

But otherwise, your suggestion would be fine.

Comment: How do I get root-relative paths?

Comment: NVM, DisgruntledGoat answered it!

Answer (score 0):

I would use something like an application base URL:

```
define('APP_URL', 'http://example.com/path/to/app');
echo '<img src="'.APP_URL.IMAGE_PATH.'">';
```

Or to have it more convenient, write a function that resolves your relative URL to an absolute URL.